# Returning everything but the first letter of a string in python

Tags: python

So I understand how to return everything but the first letter in a string in python. I want to know why coding it in a specific way does not work. My professor told me to return everything but the first letter of a string it would look something like this...

a = 'garden'

a[1:len(a) - 1]

But when I run this in the interpreter I get

'arde' instead of 'arden'.

I know that len(a) - 1 returns 5 and that the 5th indice of a is n. Also if i say something like

a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5]

I returns...

'arden'.

So what am I missing? I feel like this is just some nuance of python and I should make note of this I just wanted to make sure that I am not missing something important. Thanks!!

Comment: Array indexing in Python is zero based

Comment: Slices don't include the endpoint.

Comment: Is that something specific to python or was the prof just not thinking clearly?

Comment: In order to return everything but the first letter of a string, you will want to first find the first letter in the string. Here you seem to be assuming that the first character of the string is a letter, which may not be the case.

Comment: (Note that a[1:] also works and avoids having to worry about an off by one error (and likewise, if you wanted to get everything but the first and last letter, a[1:-1])

Answer (score 0):

Array indexing in Python is zero based.

Try:
    a = 'garden'

```
a[:-1]
```

Output:

```
garde
```

Note that if you do not specify the start index, zero is assumed.

Answer (score 0):

A Python slice [j:k] is from position **j**, in zero-based indexing, up to *but not including* position k.  Thus, a[1:5] gets you elements 1, 2, 3, & 4 -- 5 (which is the *sixth* element) is not included.

As **Foon** already noted, the canonical way to do this is simply

```
a[1:]
```

A missing slice value is assumed to be the "reasonable" end: 0 on the left, -1 (last element) on the right, and 1 for the interval (usually omitted).  Thus, a typical way to copy an entire string or list is with

```
new = old[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although already answered by EnginnerCamp here's an illustration to help you.

The array starts at zero so the string is stored as

```
0  1  2  3  4  5
g  a  r  d  e  n
```

The length of this string is **6** but, because we start counting at zero the last character is at location **5** in the string array.

When you run `a[1:len(a) - 1]` the instructions you are giving are;

```
take string a                      'garden'
start at position 1                'a' (because the 'g' is at position 0)
find the length of a                6
subtract 1                          5
end at the 5th item BUT start at 0 'e'
```

So your output string is from your code is `arde`

To get everything *except* the first character you should use `a[1:]`

It will frustrate you to start with, then become natural as you gain practice.